# What are Canny thresolds?

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, edge-detection

Is it possible to make [Canny](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/feature_detection.html?highlight=canny#canny) to ignore short edges or to ignore low gradient edges? In my case I have card lying on wood and see numerous edges of wood structure after canny

[image]

What two thresholds in canny functions are for?

Answer (score 4):

> Large intensity gradients are more likely to correspond to edges than
>   small intensity gradients. It is in most cases impossible to specify a
>   threshold at which a given intensity gradient switches from
>   corresponding to an edge into not doing so. Therefore Canny uses
>   thresholding with hysteresis.
>
> Thresholding with hysteresis requires two thresholds – high and low.
>   Making the assumption that important edges should be along continuous
>   curves in the image allows us to follow a faint section of a given
>   line and to discard a few noisy pixels that do not constitute a line
>   but have produced large gradients. Therefore we begin by applying a
>   high threshold. This marks out the edges we can be fairly sure are
>   genuine. Starting from these, using the directional information
>   derived earlier, edges can be traced through the image. While tracing
>   an edge, we apply the lower threshold, allowing us to trace faint
>   sections of edges as long as we find a starting point.
>
> Once this process is complete we have a binary image where each pixel
>   is marked as either an edge pixel or a non-edge pixel. From
>   complementary output from the edge tracing step, the binary edge map
>   obtained in this way can also be treated as a set of edge curves,
>   which after further processing can be represented as polygons in the
>   image domain.

See also:

> Thresholds: the use of two thresholds with hysteresis allows more
>   flexibility than in a single-threshold approach, but general problems
>   of thresholding approaches still apply. A threshold set too high can
>   miss important information. On the other hand, a threshold set too low
>   will falsely identify irrelevant information (such as noise) as
>   important. It is difficult to give a generic threshold that works well
>   on all images. No tried and tested approach to this problem yet
>   exists.

In your case you can probably increase the threshold value a bit to see if it reduces the short lines a bit more.

Source:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canny_edge_detector#Tracing_edges_through_the_image_and_hysteresis_thresholding

**Update**:

For this image I would perhaps pre-process it by applying lower contrast to it. This can help reduce the details in the background of the image a bit before you run it through the blurring and line detector.

Answer (score 2):

Using [GaussianBlur()](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=gaussianblur#gaussianblur) before `Canny` will help remove much of the unwanted detail. And maybe increase the low threshhold as @Ken suggested

Comment: As you see my image is blurred well. But I used `blur()`. Namely gaussian will help? Also I noticed, that blurring not only remove noise, but also blurres edges to detect with canny.

Comment: `GaussianBlurr()` is more appropriate filter to use. `blur()` is just a box filter and can introduce artifacts.  Nothing to lose by trying it.

Comment: Canny's thresholds are for blurring; this should be equivalent to increasing both the thresholds by some amount.

Comment: @beerbajay Canny thresholds are nothing to do with blurring. Go to http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/canny_detector/canny_detector.html and read about "Hysteresis"

Comment: @B... Ah, quite right. I think I got confused by the matlab implementation which accepts a sigma parameter in addition to the thresholds. Thanks for clearing that up, anyhow.